# Spring global data binding

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a custom date binder in my controller that uses the following code:

```
@InitBinder
private void dateBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    // The date format to parse or output your dates
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    // Create a new CustomDateEditor
    CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
    // Register it as custom editor for the Date type
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
}
```

This is working fine, however I'm trying to apply this globally, to do that, I created a class

```
public class ClinicBindingInitializer implements WebBindingInitializer {

    @Override
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest arg1) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        // Create a new CustomDateEditor
        CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
    }
}
```

and adding the following configuration in my servlet-context.xml

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
    <beans:property name="webBindingInitializer" ref="webBindingInitializer"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="webBindingInitializer"
    class="br.com.appus.hub.infrastructure.web.ClinicBindingInitializer">
</beans:bean>
```

and removing the init bind in the controller. However it doesn't work. I checked some places and it seems like it is correct. Is there anything else that I should do?

Edit: Forgot to mention the version of Spring. 3.1.1

Comment: If you're using Spring 3.2 or higher then, this can directly be done in a class annotated by `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: Edited my question. I'm using Spring 3.1.1.

Comment: webBindingInitializer bean should have ClinicBindingInitializer as class..?

Comment: That was a typo in my answer. Fixed

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the default `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` (registered by the `annotation-config tag`) is handling the request first.

Try setting a order in your handler adapter or use a `ConversionService` instead.

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
    <beans:property name="webBindingInitializer" ref="webBindingInitializer"/>
    <beans:property name="order" value="0" />  <!-- default value is Integer.MAX_VALUE -->
</beans:bean>
```